# How to make default value of datagridviewcell blank

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview

right now I have a vb.net program that reads in an excel file and displays the contents into a datagridview. My goal is to have code that tells the user if there is any value besides 1 or blank in the cell. Then I want to supply a default value of blank to the datagridviewcell. I was easily able to do all of this if the default value was 1 but when I change it to blank (String.empty) the program will keep the invalid input. Here is my code below. If anyone can figure out how to make the program supply a blank value as default value I would greatly appreciate it! :)

```
Sub validateDGV(rowindex, columnindex)

    Dim value As String = DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells(columnindex).Value.ToString
    If (columnindex = 1) Then
        Dim cellData = DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells(columnindex).Value
        If cellData Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(cellData) OrElse cellData.ToString = String.Empty Then
            'Do nothing because this is allowed
        ElseIf cellData <> 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Value must be 1 or Blank")
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells(columnindex).Value = String.Empty 'This should be supplying the default value of blank back to my datagridview but its not :(
            Exit Sub

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you try passing a nothing as value? .Cells(columnindex).Value = Nothing

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes I've tried "Nothing" and it still isn't working for me

Comment: I'd try this: add .ToString to the line the populates CellData and adjust the code for the string value.  And Dim cellData as a String.

Comment: Note you can use the grid's CellFormatting event to change font/background color or set ErrorProvider text.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using the OleDB I have to set my cellData variable equal to "DBNull.Value" instead of String.Empty